# ActiveMQ: consume specific stream

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, activemq-classic

I have a JAX-RS endpoint that consumes a JSON payload:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postEnvelope(final InputStream is) {
    ...
```

I want to stream this JSON InputStream into ActiveMQ:

```
    ...
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("envelopes");
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
    StreamMessage streamMessage = session.createStreamMessage();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 100];
    for (int count; (count = is.read(bytes)) > 0; ) {
        streamMessage.clearBody();
        streamMessage.writeBytes(bytes, 0, count);
        producer.send(streamMessage);
    }
    ...
```

I then want another thread to consume the ActiveMQ JSON stream and write it to an OutputStream:

```
    ...
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination envelopesQueue = session.createQueue("envelopes");
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(envelopesQueue);
    Message message = consumer.receive();
    if (message instanceof StreamMessage) {
        do {
            StreamMessage streamMessage = (StreamMessage) message;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 100];
            for (int count; (count = streamMessage.readBytes(bytes)) > 0; ) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        } while ((message = consumer.receive(2500)) != null);
    }
    ...
```

My Question is; How do I make sure my ActiveMQ consumer **only** receives messages associated with a specific JSON stream? (ie: If two JSON payloads are posted to the REST endpoint at the exact same time, then how do I prevent them both from being written to the same OutputStream).

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want. You have a producer and consumer with MQ, and you have a JAX-RS endpoint. Say I have a message in JSON, and I post it to the endpoint, would it then be sent to the queue through the producer, and then handled by the consumer?

Comment: Messages on the queue can have properties like a correlation Id, I think... If you want to send messages with different correlation ids to different outputstreams, you can (although that will probably not help you?) Or are you talking about a mutex to ensure that both messages are not written at the same time to the single outputstream?

Comment: @KoosGadellaa To answer your first question: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @KoosGadellaa In response to your second message: I'm in search of a clean implementation to handle multiple streams at once. Each stream will be written to their own OutputStream. I suppose a "correlation id" would do the trick, however that seems like complex multiplexing-type code.

Comment: If you're aiming for mulitple outputstreams, there shouldn't be much of a problem. Depending on your setup, your consumer is either a singleton (and messages are read one at a time from the queue, and there's no interference to start with as they are all handled separately), or there are multiple consumers. As long as they each have their own (*local*) outputstream, what problem are you thinking of?

Comment: The StreamMessage scheme I'm using is firing chunks of the input source into the queue. If two input streams are chunked up and fired into the queue, then 1 consumer will receive StreamMessages from both. So, they're not "handled separately" (unless of course I using this API wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question; I'm no longer using the StreamMessage API. Instead my POST endpoint is saving the input stream to a file, and I'm sending a TextMessage containing the URL of where to retrieve the file.